# Three.js how to add circle in center of scene

Tags: three.js

I work with sphere image and use for it Three.js and I need to add some small object like aim in center of the sphere, and when I will move scene this object should be always in center of scene.

Comment: Please include code showing what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var cubeGeometry = new THREE.CircleGeometry(2, 100);
    var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xffffff, side: THREE.DoubleSide, transparent: true, opacity: 0.5, depthTest: false});
    var cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, cubeMaterial);
    this.camera.add(cube)
    cube.position.set( 0, 0, -55 );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add the aim to the sphere and it will move with it in the middle:

```
sphere.add(aim);
```